# Maven: Transitive - Circular Dependency - Release Process

Tags: java, git, jakarta-ee, maven, maven-2

Here is my project structure,

```
Parent
^ ^ ^
| | |

A B C
```

Project A, B , C depends on Parent. Parent has a dependency management section, which determines the version of A, B and C.

During the release process , I release the parent first, which will have the yet to be release version of A, B, C. Then change the parent of A, B and C to the newest version of parent.

```
A -> C, B->A and C->A
```

Now because of the above dependency, I cannot determine the order of release of A, B and C.
If I release A first, it will complain that release version of C is not available ( because the parent declared the version of C during its release, ahead of time). I cannot release C first, because it depends on A.

I have Parent , A, B and C as individual repos on Git. Is there a way , I can resolve this.

Comment: There must be a reason why A and C depend on each other , why ? May be you can strip out the common part that A and C shares into another project D, like this: A -> D, B -> A, C -> A -> D. Then release D first, then A, then B and C.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to resolve this is to remove the circular dependencies between A, B and C. Maven enforces that there doesn't exist circular dependencies. To remove that circle you will have to factor out a common part of one pair of the projects A, B and C into a new module D. So if you choose to open the cycle between A and B, they would therefore only depend on D.

This way your release process will also be much simpler as you can release everything in the same job.